# Automatically apply symbology appropriate to each layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, symbology, arcgis-10.5

I was wondering whether there was a way to save and apply a symbology configuration.

I am not trying to use the same symbology from one layer on multiple other layers, rather apply the symbology configuration I am looking for.

For example:
I am trying to apply the "Quantile" classification method with specific numerical formatting options. It would be great if I could save this setting as a profile and reuse it somehow.

Applying the symbology from the same layer wouldn't work as the value classification in each layer is different, please correct me if there are workarounds to this limitation.

Comment: @Midavalo it doesn't have to be in arcpy, and it doesn't have to be in GUI. It can be in MS Paint for all I care. The method is unimportant as long I get the result. Thanks.

Comment: Just to clarify the language in your example...the way I read it sounds contradictory: you want to be able to save the classification type "with specific numerical formatting options" but later you say you don't want to re-use the symbology from another layer because "the value classification in each layer is different".  Can you reconcile these two statements? (It's highly likely that I'm just misunderstanding your point here).

Comment: Hi Matt. As an example, the numerical formatting option would be a percentage with 2 significant digits. I would like to apply that across all layers as default. When it comes to the distribution of the data, I would like to apply a Quantile based distribution that takes into account the data range and segments it accordingly.

Comment: A layer package or map package probably just saves the layers and symbologies within the package itself, but have you looked into those options?

Comment: What happens when you save your layer as a layer file?  I would have expected that to save your layer symbology exactly as you have configured it.

Comment: i think you need to create a new attribute in each feature class that normalizes the values to each other so that the same symbology can be used.